# django - 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, django

When I was using python 2.7 the code was working fine.
But when I installed python 3.4 and runserver, I get typeerror which occurs 
on lines that starts with "return render_to_response"(3 place).

Exception value is "'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".
I am not sure this error is caused by version difference.

The code is writen bellow.

Thank you.

```
def notice(request, page_id = 1): 

  context = RequestContext(request)
  if not request.user.has_perm("board/category1_can_read"):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
  post_list = Post.objects.filter(category=1)[::-1]
  cut = len(post_list)/6
  if not len(post_list)%6:
    cut -= 1
  if (cut <= 0) and (1 < page_id):
    max_page = 1
    raise Http404
  else:
    max_page = cut + 1
  i = int(page_id) - 1

  post_list = post_list[i*6:(i+1)*6] #divide post list into pages (6 post per page)

  return render_to_response("board/notice.html", {"board_active": "active", "post_list": post_list, "page_id": int(page_id), "max_page": range(max_page)}, context)




def boardA(request, category_id = 2, page_id = 1):

  context = RequestContext(request)
  if not request.user.has_perm("board/category2_can_read"):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
  if 0 == int(category_id): #selected All post
    post_list = Post.objects.all()[::-1]
  else:
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(category=int(category_id))[::-1]
  cut = len(post_list)/6
  if not len(post_list)%6:
    cut -= 1
  if (cut <= 0) and (1 < page_id):
    max_page = 1
    raise Http404
  else:
    max_page = cut + 1
  i = int(page_id) - 1
  post_list = post_list[i*6:(i+1)*6]
  return render_to_response("board/boardA.html", {"boardA_active": "active", "post_list": post_list, "category_id": int(category_id), "page_id": int(page_id), "max_page": range(max_page)}, context)


def boardB(request, page_id = 1):

      context = RequestContext(request)
  if not request.user.has_perm("board/category3_can_read"):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
  post_list = Post.objects.filter(category=3)  
  cut = len(post_list)/6
  if not len(post_list)%6:
    cut -= 1
  if (cut <= 0) and (1 < page_id):
    max_page = 1
    raise Http404
  else:
    max_page = cut + 1
  i = int(page_id) - 1
  post_list = post_list[i*6:(i+1)*6]
  return render_to_response("board/boardB.html", {"boardB_active": "active", "post_list": post_list, "page_id": int(page_id), "max_page": range(max_page)}, context)
```

Comment: Error stack trace could definitely help

Comment: Try to take a look at this site https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#int

Comment: DuhProgrammer13 Could I get more specific clues about this issue?